# Excel VBA: Saving data/file to another format without macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have this userform
[image: User form]
It is fully fuctioning but I want to add a feature that is sending the file as .xlsx or .txt so I can remove the macro from the file.

I searched the internet for days and come up to a procedure that I need to make a 3 process to save it to another format. The process I come up is listed below:
1. `.SaveCopyAs`

> Copy(Filename).(Same format)

2. `.Open`

   > Existing File
3. `.SaveAs`

   > (FileName).(Any format)

And delete the SaveCopyAs file to avoid redundancy Or catch the temporary file to SaveAs another file format? Every input should be save after clicking ok button and to overwrite the existing file.

Can someone tell me if I'm making the right approach to my problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue, my solution involved copying the Sheets into a new workbook then renaming them accordingly and saving that workbook with a specific name:

```
ans = MsgBox("Would you like to export the Report?", vbYesNo)
    Select Case ans
    Case vbYes
        FPath = "C:\...\...\... Daily Report"
        FName = "Report" & ".xlsx"

        Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        'NewBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete to delete the first empty sheet on the new workbook

        If Dir(FPath & "\" & FName) <> "" Then
            MsgBox "File " & FPath & "\" & FName & " already exists"
        Else
            NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
        End If

        NewBook.Close False
        CurrentReport = FPath & "\" & FName
    Case vbNo
        Exit Sub
    End Select
```

Or to append the data to a text file, each time the user clicks "OK":

```
Sub VBA_to_append_existing_text_file()
Dim strFile_Path As String
strFile_Path = "C:\temp\test.txt" ‘Change as per your test folder and exiting file path to append it.
Open strFile_Path For Append As #1
Write #1, "This is my sample text" ' add entered data here
Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Hard part is the input is continuous so I need to make the code overwrite the existing file while the form is still running.

Comment: Why not save the data into the existing Workbook line by line, until the user clicks on the Command Button "Done", then export to a new workbook?